# Regex does not match the whole string

Tags: regex, parsing, ini

Following is the regular expression pattern I'm dealing with:

```
[\t\v\f ]*([^=\s]+)[\t\v\f ]*=[\t\v\f ]*([^=\s]+)[\t\v\f ]*(?:\r?\n\s*([^=\s]+)[\t\v\f ]*=[\t\v\f ]*([^=\s]+)\s*)*
```

It basically tries to match key value pairs in a single section of a `.ini` file. So, for instance, it should be able to match the **whole** string below:

```
"aa = 11\nbb = 22\ncc = 33"
```

I tried to test it on [this](https://regexr.com/) regex matching website and some others as well and they all seem to match **only the first 2 lines**. Here is how the match looks like **(global flag is disabled)**:

[image]

However when I try to force the regex to find all 3 lines as follows:

```
[\t\v\f ]*([^=\s]+)[\t\v\f ]*=[\t\v\f ]*([^=\s]+)[\t\v\f ]*(?:\r?\n\s*([^=\s]+)[\t\v\f ]*=[\t\v\f ]*([^=\s]+)\s*){2}
```

Then it seems to be able to match the whole string.

Can anyone give me a good reason as to why the entire string above does not match my regex? Also what regex should I use in order to match **all** key value pairs in a string like the one I wrote above?

Comment: Your first regex works if you turn on the global flag.  I haven't actually looked through it yet, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `\s*` at the end of the non-capturing group; this is being greedy and absorbing the vertical white-space at the end of the line containing `bb = 22` and preventing the group matching again on the line with `cc = 33` in it. Changing that to `[\t\v\f ]` (or even `\s*?`) makes the regex match the entire string as desired. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UmVQMY/2) on regex101. The reason it works when you add the `{2}` quantifier is that the desire to match makes the engine backtrack when processing the `\s*` to a point where it can then match the non-capturing group again.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you.